# One domain, one wordpress system, different locations, different servers, low bandwith

Tags: hosting, web-hosting, cdn

I have a website with a low bandwidth (like 80.000 views per month, 1 mega or so every page) but that offers products to clients all over the world. A very specific business.

The server is located in Spain. If someone access from Spain, then the loading time is less a second, but if someone access from Sidney, it’s about 6 seconds, which is unacceptable.

I have tried a CDN, but since there’s redirections and not all parts of the website are hosted, it does not improve the loading time a lot.

Other person had advised me to create different cloned domains with different servers, like .eu for Europe, .com for EEUU and so, but since it can be read for Google as duplicated content, and since it is not effective for me working on different domains with different wordpress systems, it is unacceptable.

Is there anything I can do? Something like a hosting that, if it detects changes in the website, then it updates their cloned websites in servers all over the world.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: All the Internet connections out of Australia are terrible. Everyone in Australia knows it, but Parliament won't fix it. They just keep making things worse. You can host a mirror of your site in Australia if it's that important, use anycast DNS or Amazon Route 53 to direct users, etc.

Comment: Thanks but, anyway, Australia is only an example. America loading times, for example, is like 4-5 seconds per page

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the latency of your hosting. Use one that has better connectivity worldwide. Being in Spain you can use any high quality provider within the European Union.

Another solution is to register an account in Cloudflare, maybe a free one, if not, a Pro account doesn't cost too much.

Comment: Thanks you, but I think I have a good hosting. I mean, I use a spain hosting, but they use OVH servers, (which I think are fine):

https://es.hostadvice.com/tools/whois/#sientemarruecos.viajes

Comment: OVH is cheap, not necessarily good. Your problem is not configuration, but the latency of your provider's connections. You need a provider with better connections or a content delivery network like Cloudflare.